# There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database happens in a brand new project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, entity-framework-migrations

I opened a new ASP.net core razor pages project.
For authentication type, I chose 'individual accounts'.
A new project was created, in Data\Migrations I see the files:
ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs and 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs

I ran 'update-database' to create the database from the migration files.
I got the error:
There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

I know this error usually happens when a database with the same name already exists, but in my case, I can see very clearly that there is no database existing with this name. (I also tried to change the name, the error never stopped)

Comment: Please share the code, ideally a [mre].

Comment: I didn't add any code.  As described above, I just opened a new project with individual accounts and tried to create the database from the migration file.

Comment: Was the database empty?

Comment: There was no database, I expected it to be created from the auto-generated migration code after running 'update-database'.

Comment: Try `drop-database`
and `update-database`, and tell us the result.

Comment: ok, now I know what my problem was.  When I tried drop-database I was asked if I am sure about deleting it, and the DB address was different than the one in the connection string.
It turned out that I had another connection string in EV, I didn't think it will have priority over the one in appsettings.json.
Erasing this EV solved the problem.
Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried drop-database and I realized that I had another connection string in EV, I didn't think it will have priority over the one in appsettings.json. Erasing this EV solved the problem. Thank you for your help